# Query opportunity from whatid on events

Tags: api, standard-objects, php, query

I am using the php api and am curious whether it is possible to get information from two objects in one query. I'm basically trying to save API calls. What I would like to do is grab information from the opportunity that an event is related to when I query the event. Is this possible? I know I can get the names and whatnot from the WhoId and WhatId, but since I have the WhoId(Opp Id) readily available, I should be able to somehow pull this off, but I'm not 100% sure how. Here is my query:

```
$mySfObject->query("select Id, WhatId, Who.Name, What.Name, StartDateTime, Outcome__c from Event where StartDateTime = THIS_MONTH and Subject = 'Some Subject'");
```

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TYPEOF`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm) in your query to pull in the Opportunity's information.